# Почему тэг video не работает в браузере Яндекс, в Chrome все работает

Tags: html, html5, видео

Добавила на сайт локальные видео

```
        <video width="100%" autoplay muted playsinline loop>
            <source src="../video/slideVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

При первом открытии сайта, появляется картинка видео( только у одного видео, а на странице у меня их 3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе или обновлении страницы картинка исчезает, видео не воспроизводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в Chrome все отлично работает. Видео воспроизводится, работает все видео на странице, при  обновлении и переходе видео не исчезают. С чем это может быть связано.

Поискала решения в интернете, попробовала указывать разные форматы.

```
       <video width="100%" autoplay muted playsinline loop>
            <source src="../video/slideVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="../video/slideVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="../video/slideVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
```

Но и это не помогло, в Chrome все работает, в Яндексе нет. А в safari вообще только одно видео не работает, а остальные работают.

Comment: скорее всего видео используют разные кодеки, и форматы. конвертируйте все видео в один формат. http://htmlbook.ru/html/video

Comment: видео у меня все в формате mp4, кодеки я нигде не указывала